# Reinitialize owl carousel 2

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using owl carousel version 2.
I have a page which shows different logos about different catalogues.

My use case is:

when I am in home page I show a different items in the carousel. So, I have also a filter above the slider, to filter for example by category.

When I click on the filter, no one call to backend is made.

In some way I am able to hide/show in the slider, the logo which I have to show or not.

My problem is when I hide the logo useless, the slider has always the initial dimension, so I see spaces between visible logos (the spaces are the hidden logos).

I read other issue on stackoverflow and, after have to hidden the useless logos, I tried:

```
$("#owl-header").owlCarousel({
  items: 'number of item to display',
  navigation: true
});
```

But nothing happens :-(

Please help me!

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear. You want it to reinitialise or not? Please add jsFiddle with working demo.

Comment: I have a slider with 5 items, for example. Then I delete some items.
At this stage I see the slider with initial configuration, I mean, where was the position of items deleted, I see a space, an empty item...

Comment: add jsFiddle for the same.

Comment: It's useless write in jsFiddle. My goal is: after deleted some item in carousel, I want refresh the slider.

Comment: I followed this https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues/1536,
but it doesn't work

Comment: In the end I used slick slider... it fits good for me!
thanks